# How to programmatically add radar charts?

Tags: r, echarts4r

### Goal

Get data in a shiny app and display a radar chart. The data may have multiple columns with different column names (as user names differ).

### Example

Here is a simple example with 3 columns that I put in a radar chart:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tibble)

data_long <- tibble::tibble(
  Construct = c("C", "A", "B"),
  radar1 = c(10, 50, 100),
  calcu2 = c(50, 90, 5),
  foker = c(15, 35, 75)
)

data_long |>
  e_charts(Construct) |>
  e_radar(radar1, max = 100) |>
  e_radar(calcu2) |>
  e_radar(foker)
```

The challenge I have is that the column names other than "Construct" will be user names. So, I would not know the column names beforehand. The `e_radar` function requires a column name. How do I programmatically build the radar chart without knowing the number and names of columns?

Comment: Would the number of columns of dataframe differ? If not you can use indexing.

Comment: @Golem Yes, the number of columns can differ. Also, indexing does not work with `e_radar`. It requires the name of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make a generic e_radar function. You can use `e_radar_()` instead of `e_radar()`

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tibble)

e_radar_unknown_columns <- function(df = NULL){
  
  radarPlot <- df |>
    e_charts(Construct)
  
  for (i in 2:length(df)){
    radarPlot <- radarPlot |>
      e_radar_(names(df)[i], max = 100)
  }
  
  return(radarPlot)  
}

data_long <- tibble::tibble(
  Construct = c("C", "A", "B"),
  oter = c(10, 50, 100),
  calcu2 = c(50, 90, 5),
  foker = c(15, 35, 75)
)

data_long2 <- tibble::tibble(
  Construct = c("C", "A", "B"),
  radar1 = c(10, 50, 100),
  calcu2 = c(1, 100, 55),
  foker = c(50, 40, 90)
)

data_long3 <- tibble::tibble(
  Construct = letters[1:10],
  name1 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name2 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name3 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name4 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name5 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name6 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name7 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name8 = sample(1:100, 10),
  name9 = sample(1:100, 10)
)

e_radar_unknown_columns(data_long)
e_radar_unknown_columns(data_long2)
e_radar_unknown_columns(data_long3)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works for the data in the code samples. I was wondering what to do if the column names contain backticks due to spaces? `names(df)` won't work in that case.

Comment: Did you try? I would expect it just works.

Comment: Yes, I tried. `names(df)` removes the backticks in names and then echarts doesn't recognize them.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, because it just works on my machine. I tested it with column names that contain white spaces. Maybe you can make a new SO question for it?